# Como utilizar credenciais em um HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou tentando capturar uma imagem a partir de uma câmera IP. No primeiro modelo testado, funcionou normalmente, tendo em vista que o modelo em teste não solicitava credenciais para devolver as imagens como um `array de bytes` porque as credenciais já vinham na linha de comando CGI requisitada, como segue:

> http://192.168.0.25:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr={usuário}&pwd={senha}

Segue abaixo código funcionando do primeiro modelo.

```
Uri geturi = new Uri(_cgi);
//Solicita um comando CGI para câmera FOSCAM
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(geturi);
byte[] imgByte = null;
//Pega a Resposta do comando CGI, neste comando uma imagem.
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
   {
       if (response != null)
         {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
               {
                  imgByte = reader.ReadBytes(1 * 640 * 480 * 10);
               }
          }
   }
```

Para o novo modelo de câmera, a mesma solicita as credenciais na hora de retornar uma imagem, como segue o exemplo na imagem abaixo, testado a partir de um navegador.

[image: Teste no navegador]

Segue o comando CGI requisitado:

> http://{usuário}:{senha}@192.168.0.29:80/Streaming/channels/1/picture

Segue abaixo o código inoperante do segundo modelo de câmera IP testada.

```
Uri geturi = new Uri(_cgi);
string username = "usuário";
string password = "senha";

//Seta as credenciais
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(geturi, "Basic", cred);

//Solicita um comando CGI para câmera FOSCAM
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(geturi);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = cache;
byte[] imgByte = null;

//Pega a Resposta do comando CGI, neste comando uma imagem.
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
   if (response != null)
      {
         using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
               imgByte = reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10);
               //Converte os Bytes para um bitmap.
               if (BytesToBitmap(imgByte) != null)
                  {
                      RunOnUiThread(() =>
                      {
                         _image.SetImageBitmap(BytesToBitmap(imgByte));
                      });
                      return true;
                  }
            }
            return false;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Se alguém tiver algum outro método para adicionar credenciais e quiser apresentar, será bem vindo para testes.

### EDIT 1

fiz alteração no método `cache.Add(geturi, "Basic", cred);` para `cache.Add(geturi, "NTLM", cred);`. Porém, os dois retornam a seguinte mensagem

> Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)

Sendo que, via navegador de internet tenho acesso normal e o ip testado pinga normalmente na câmera.